# Sending a different object to an Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have an array of ComboBoxes:

```
ComboBox[] boxes = new ComboBox[3]{ComboBox box1, ComboBox box2, ComboBox box3};
```

Each ComboBox gets passed to the same event handler when their indexes are changed:

```
foreach (ComboBox box in boxes)
{
  box.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.Box_Changed);
}
```

What I would like to do is pass not a single ComboBox, but the entire `boxes[]` array to the event handler. How can I do this?

Comment: not sure to understand ; how would you attach an event to an array when an array doesn't raise events ?

Comment: *you* dont "send" or pass them to the handler: WIndows does in response to the user click.  If you could, your next question would be how to tell which one was *really* clicked.  You can always reference the others in the event code.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. Would it be possible to make the array global, and access it from inside the event handler?

Comment: If `boxes` is declared at the form level, then you can just use the `boxes` variable.

Comment: If the array is declared at the form level, it is already available.  The Q provides no context for that.  If it is not, you can still reference the controls

Comment: The array must be in the form because the control have to be in the form to raise events handled in it (unless i missed something big)

Comment: Well, it could be declared in some method, in which case it would be a local array which exists only in that method.  "in the form" != 'at the form level` (LarsTech worded it more precisely than I).

Comment: @Sehnsucht Not necessarily. If you declare that array and add those controls in the form's constructor, that variable won't be available any longer (but the controls are available in the form's control's collection).

Comment: But they have to be in the form so available through its' Controls collection (comments collision ^^)

Comment: The OP's array must be local; the controls would not exist if the first line is initialization code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really change the what's sent to the callback, as that's called by the framework on your behalf.

You can either find somewhere else to store the data, like the .Tag property of each ComboBox, or you can create a simple little helper method that knows about the ComboBox and let it pass that data along for you.

```
public void Example(ComboBox[] boxes)
{
    // Using a statement lambda to wrap the call
    foreach (ComboBox box in boxes)
    {
        box.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            Box_Changed_Example1(boxes, sender, e);
        });
    }

    // Or, use the .Tag property to store the data
    foreach (ComboBox box in boxes)
    {
        box.Tag = boxes;
        box.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Box_Changed_Example2);
    }
}

void Box_Changed_Example1(ComboBox[] boxes, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO
}

void Box_Changed_Example2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox[] boxes = (ComboBox[])((ComboBox)sender).Tag;
    // TODO
}
```